# CSV parsing conditions in PHP

Tags: php, excel, parsing, csv

I created a CSV parser that works fine for some CSV files I've found online, but one that I converted from XLS to CSV via Microsoft Excel 2011 does not work.
The ones that work are formatted as such:

> "Sort Order","Common Name","Formal Name","Type","Sub Type","Sovereignty","Capital","ISO 4217 Currency Code","ISO 4217 Currency Name","ITU-T Telephone Code","ISO 3166-1 2 Letter Code","ISO 3166-1 3 Letter Code","ISO 3166-1 Number","IANA Country Code TLD"
>   "1","Afghanistan","Islamic State of Afghanistan","Independent State",,,"Kabul","AFN","Afghani","+93","AF","AFG","004",".af".........................etc...

The one that doesn't work is formatted like this:

> Order Id,Date Ordered,Date Returned,Product Id,Description,Order Reason Code,Return Qty,Order Return Comment,Ship To Name,Ship To Address1,Ship To Address2,Ship To Address3,Ship To City,Ship To State,Ship To Zipcode,Ship To Country,Disposition,Ship To Email,ShipVia
>   5555555,2013-07-05 13:58:36.000,2013-08-16 00:00:00.000,5555-55,0555 - Some Test Thing,Refund,2,,jeric  beatty,123 fake st,,,burke,NJ,55055,US,Discard,test@test.com,Super Fast Shipping

Is there anyway to get excel to export in the format as the first one?  I would like to avoid doing this manually as the file is huge and I would have to manually edit lots of parts of it where I couldn't do a "replace all".  Another issue could be that there are double and sometimes triple commas in some places.  Though this does appear in both files.

Here is the parser:

```
    function ingest_csv() {

  $file_url = 'http://www.path.to/csv/file.csv';
  $record_num = 0;
  $records = array();
  $header = array();
  if (($handle = fopen($file_url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $records['id'] = '';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
      $records['id'][$record_num] = '';
      $cell_num = 0;
      foreach ($data as $cell) {
        if($record_num == 0) {
          $header = $data;
        } else {
          $current_key = $header[$cell_num];
          $records['id'][$record_num][$current_key] = $cell;
        }
        $cell_num++;
      }
      $record_num++;

    }

    fclose($handle);
  }
  else {
    echo 'could not open file.';
  }
  return array($record_num, $records);
}

function batch_csv() {
  list($num_rows, $rows) = ingest_csv
  print_r($num_rows);
  print_r($rows);
}
```

Comment: why write your own csv parser? PHP has [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and [fputcsv()](http://php.net/fputcsv). You should fix your XSL to produce valid csv instead of trying to hack together a parser than can try to accommodate mangled inputs.

Comment: look at the function arguments for `fgetcsv()` you just need to adjust those for each format.

Comment: @MarcB I think you miss-understood the question as what you suggested is what I was asking how to do.  I was not trying to fix my PHP, just my XSL.

> "Is there anyway to get excel to export in the format as the first one?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments though you may be trying to reinvent the wheel here, though personally I've asked questions where I didn't want to give long rambling explanations of why I was forced to use unconventional approaches so should this be one of those situations here's an answer.

In OpenOffice Calculator (for example) and when you go to save as CSV you get a number of further options including the decision to double quote all fields.

Unfortunately Excel doesn't give you the choice, but Microsoft do offer up a workaround using a macro - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291296/en-us

Comment: Thank you for understanding!  I will use OpenOffice to export what I need.